# Generating an abstract base class Python

Tags: python, abstract-class

**Problem:**

I'd like to generate an abstract class with a few method stubs that should be implemented by its sub-classes thereby avoiding any hard-coding.

That is, if I define a class as follows:

```
>>> class Sample(SomeClass):    
...    ACTIONS = ('run', 'sleep', 'kill')
```

The above class should always implement the methods `run`, `sleep`, and `kill`.

**Attempted solution:**

The snippet below works as expected and raises an error when the abstract method `run` is not defined in subclass `FooBar`.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
...     
...     @abstractmethod
...     def run(self, *args, **kwargs):        
...         pass    


>>> class FooBar(Foo):
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b

>>> FooBar(1, 2)        
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class FooBar with abstract methods run
```

I was trying to achieve the same by generating the `Foo` class using `type`:

```
>>> Foo2 = type('Foo', (), {'__metaclass__': ABCMeta, 
...                         'run'          : abstractmethod(lambda self, *args, **kwargs: None)})

>>> class FooBar(Foo2):
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
```

However, the below call does not raise any error:

```
>>> FooBar(1, 2)        
<__main__.FooBar at ...>
```

Noticed that `__abstractmethods__` doesn't get defined in `Foo2` (comparing `vars(Foo)` and `vars(Foo2)`).

I did find a similar attempt [here](https://gist.github.com/demianbrecht/6944269), but wasn't able to follow why the above wouldn't work and why I can't make use of `ABCMeta` directly (which defines `__new__` in a generic manner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized I could just do this :)

```
>>> Foo2 = ABCMeta('Foo', (), {'run': abstractmethod(lambda self, *args, **kwargs: None)})

>>> FooBar(1, 2)
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class FooBar with abstract methods run
```